# rsync: /usr/lib/libpopt.so.0: no version information available (required by rsync)

Tags: linux, linker, version, rsync, shared-objects

I got this error when I executed the command "rsync / /tmp".

It seems to be a warning, but still I wanted to eliminate this warning. How do I resolve this?

If it is a version issue in library, how do I know which version of library I have and what it expects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there were two libraries (popt library) being generated in the same location with same version number. This is how the sequence flow happened in my case.

1) first popt library (libpopt.so.0) is built.
2) rsync is built using the first libpopt.so.0 generated in step(1).
3) Another modified popt library (libpopt.so.0) is built and placed in the same location where the first popt library is generated.
4) Hence rsync uses a particular popt library for building. It tried to use different popt library while running.

The solution is to remove any of the popt library. I did and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You get rsync dependencies with

```
[root]# ldd /usr/bin/rsync
        libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x0000003aa8c00000)
        libpopt.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpopt.so.0 (0x0000003730c00000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000372e800000)
        libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x0000003aa8800000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000372e400000)
```

Then you get package using yum:

```
[root]# yum provides  /usr/lib64/libpopt.so.0
Importing additional filelist information
popt-1.10.2.3-34.el5.x86_64 : A C library for parsing command line parameters.
Repo        : redhat
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libpopt.so.0
```

So

```
yum reinstall popt
```

Should provide your dependenvy

Comment: Unfortunately I am having minimal version of linux in My virtual machine. I do not have ldd command. My VM is 32 bit and it doesn't have problem in locating libpopt.so file. It is available in the location /usr/lib/libpopt.so file. I always tried strace command with rsync and it is trying to open the file /usr/lib/libpopt.so file only.